# How to identify if an image have an embed sRGB icc profile?

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagick, color-profile, color-management

I would like to remove from my images their sRGB profile if they have one. the problem i don't know how to identify that an image have a sRGB profile. What the good way to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Imagemagick, use

```
convert image.suffix -format "%[profiles]\n" info:
```

or

```
convert image.suffix -format "%[profile:icc]\n" info:
```

unless your Imagemagick version is ancient.

For example:

```
convert logo.jpg  -format "%[profiles]\n" info:
icc
```

```
convert logo.jpg  -format "%[profile:icc]\n" info:
sRGB built-in
```

Comment: thanks fmw42 :) do you know how i can do this with magickWand api ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know any of the APIs for Imagemagick, only the command line. Have you looked at https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-property.php#MagickGetImageProfiles

Comment: You might post the solution to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not accept as the answer as Fred has already shown you the way, but here's how you can get the profile with PHP Imagick:

```
$img = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$img->setOption('format','%[profiles]');
$img->setImageFilename('info:');

$fd = fopen('php://memory','rwb');
$img->writeImageFile($fd);
fseek($fd, 0);
$info = fread($fd, 1024);
fclose($fd);
var_dump($info);
```

**Sample Output**

```
string(18) "app12,exif,icc,xmp"
```